# Overflow-x scroll not working, child divs shrinking

Tags: css

I wanted to make a parent div with child div's scrollable. I've set fixed width for the child div's but they are shrinking. Therefore the div can't be scrollable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#main {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

#main div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The flex-wrap Property</h1>

<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:coral;">A</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">B</div>
  <div style="background-color:khaki;">C</div>
  <div style="background-color:pink;">D</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightgrey;">E</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightgreen;">F</div>
</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 10 and earlier versions do not support the flex-wrap property.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code as **text**.

Answer (score 0):

This will make the child divs scrollable **(Vertically)**.

**CSS**

```
#main {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
flex-direction: column;
overflow-y: scroll;
}

#main div {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
line-height: 47px;
}
```

**Html**

```
<h1>The flex-wrap Property</h1>

<div id="main">
<div style="background-color:coral;">A</div>
<div style="background-color:lightblue;">B</div>
<div style="background-color:khaki;">C</div>
<div style="background-color:pink;">D</div>
<div style="background-color:lightgrey;">E</div>
<div style="background-color:lightgreen;">F</div>
</div>
```

This will make the child divs scrollable **(Horizontally)**

**CSS**

```
#main {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
flex-direction: row;
overflow-x: scroll;

}

#main div {
width: 100%;
padding: 43px;
}
```

**Html**

```
<h1>The flex-wrap Property</h1>

<div id="main">
<div style="background-color:coral;">A</div>
<div style="background-color:lightblue;">B</div>
<div style="background-color:khaki;">C</div>
<div style="background-color:pink;">D</div>
<div style="background-color:lightgrey;">E</div>
<div style="background-color:lightgreen;">F</div>
</div>
```

```css
#main {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
flex-direction: row;
overflow-x: scroll;

}

#main div {
width: 100%;
padding: 43px;
}
```

```html
<h1>The flex-wrap Property</h1>

<div id="main">
<div style="background-color:coral;">A</div>
<div style="background-color:lightblue;">B</div>
<div style="background-color:khaki;">C</div>
<div style="background-color:pink;">D</div>
<div style="background-color:lightgrey;">E</div>
<div style="background-color:lightgreen;">F</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adjust padding according to your needs.